# Project statistics seem to be "stuck" in Scrivener

Tags: wordcount, scrivener

Recently, every time I run project statistics it shows the same word count, regardless of how much new content I've written. It's been stuck on 109,015 words for my last three writing sessions. I believe the character count is stuck as well, though it's not something I pay attention to. The first time I noticed it, it scared the crap out of me as I thought I had lost what I had written that day.

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b I believe OP is asking about Scrivener, but it would be nice to have some confirmation from them.

Comment: Oh crap yes, it's Scrivener. I'm sorry, I was directed here and thought it was just about that software.

Comment: Valkyrie, welcome to our site! Could you please [edit] your post to incorporate that important software detail *into the question* rather than leaving it in a comment. Comments can easily be overlooked, and can even be deleted. For further guidance, see [ask] and take our [Tour]. :-)

Comment: Sorry to redirect you again, but I think your question (that seems to be a support question) would be easiest answered by the people that create Scrivener: https://forum.literatureandlatte.com/ Start with a search and go from there: https://forum.literatureandlatte.com/search?q=statistics%20stuck